# SQL getting a percentage from a column of quantities

Tags: sql, sql-server, ajax

I have a set of shelves and some are not being used but some are. I want to get the percentage of shelves that are being used (I am using an ajax call from javascript) what is a good way to do this and could you please provide an example?

This is the query I have so far which gets the nulls and sets the quantity to 0:

```
SELECT warehouse_locations.location, ISNULL(product_stock_warehouse.quantity, 0) as quantity 
FROM product_stock_warehouse 
RIGHT JOIN warehouse_locations ON product_stock_warehouse.location = warehouse_locations.location 
WHERE warehouse_locations.location LIKE 'A21%' 
ORDER BY product_stock_warehouse.quantity
```

[image]

If the shelf is not 0, it is "Full" and therefore counts towards the percentage being used.

I am using MS-SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need aggregation.  The idea is something like this:

```
SELECT wl.location, COALESCE(SUM(psw.quantity), 0) as total_quantity,
       (CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(psw.quantity), 0) = 0 THEN 'EMPTY' ELSE 'USED' END) as status
FROM warehouse_locations wl LEFT JOIN
     product_stock_warehouse  psw
     ON psw.location = wl.location 
WHERE wl.location LIKE 'A21%'
GROUP BY wl.location
ORDER BY psw.quantity;
```

Some notes:

- `LEFT JOIN` is much easier to follow than `RIGHT JOIN`.  It means "keep all rows in the first table" rather than "keep all rows in some table later in the `FROM` clause that I haven't seen yet".
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- Use `GROUP BY` to get one row per "shelf", which I assume is the same as a "location".

Comment: Do you know how I could use this to get a percentage to javascript that I can use in html?